# Which tools ISPs use for browsing logs?

Tags: isp, log-analysis

It is known that ISP has to log various network data for various purposes, such as law enforcement needs.

However, what are some examples of software tools used by ISPs to browse this huge amount of network logs?

In addition, how time-consuming is for ISP, for example, to look for a user behind a given IP address if they have been subpoenaed?

Comment: For the "how time-consuming" part, it is a matter of a fraction of a second. Like searching for security.stackexchange.com on your search engine. How promptly they coordinate with law enforcement, will make the real difference. See [my recent question and the comments.](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/57866/online-crime-subpoena-search-and-arrest)